# Detect colors ratio in image for iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, image-processing

I want to detect colors from Image, I am getting images frame by frame with the help of AVFoundation's classes for live camera. Now I want to detect red color from image and to make operation after getting red color. I read this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448125/how-to-get-pixel-data-from-a-uiimage-cocoa-touch-or-cgimage-core-graphics) but couldn't find any healthy solution. Is this possible for not using external library? Any tutorial or helping material would be helpful for me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.
        Call this method when touch move and touch begin occurs in screen:

```
-(void) getPixelColorAtLocation:(CGPoint)point {

unsigned char pixel[4] = {0};
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixel, 1, 1, 8, 4, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -point.x, -point.y);
[self.layer renderInContext:context];
CGContextRelease(context);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
        if((pixel[0]=255) && (pixel[1] = 0) && (pixel[2] = 0)){
     //if pixel are red then this condition become true

}
```

Use this method for getting image:

```
- (UIImage *)drawLineFromPoint:(CGPoint)fromPoint toPoint:(CGPoint)toPoint image:(UIImage *)image
{

}
```

You can call it like this:

```
self.image = [self drawLineFromPoint:previousPoint  toPoint:point image:self.image];
```

Comment: Thanks Keyur, at this code i am passing CGPoint but where and how I can set UIImage to this method in which it detects colors ratio? Thanks again.

Comment: I have edit my code pls try if you will face any prb let me know

Comment: Thanks, Buddy I already have UIImage but I want to ask that how can I pass this image to "-(void) getPixelColorAtLocation:(CGPoint)point" method as you are just passing CGPoint but where is UIImage? how you are getting pixels from Image?

Comment: I think here no need to pass uiimage you just pass you touch point

Comment: I don't think so I need UITouch, I already have UIImage, how to read pixels from already Image?

Comment: -(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    UITouch *mytouch=[[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
    [myPath addLineToPoint:[mytouch locationInView:self]];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
    [img setNeedsDisplay];
    */
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
    [self getPixelColorAtLocation:currentPoint]; 
}

Comment: I know the touch moved method but there is no role of touches in my app. I just have an output Image now I want to play with this image, is to fetch colors from it. Are you getting my problem?